# ¿Como puedo quitar un parámetro de mi URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess

tengo una archivo index.php con el siguiente codigo:

```
<?php
    $page = isset($_GET['p']) ? strtolower($_GET['p']) : 'home';
    require_once "modules/header.php";
    require_once "modules/".$page.".php";
    require_once "modules/footer.php"; 
?>
```

y el header tiene lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    <li class="nav-item <?php echo $page == 'home' ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="?p=home" class="nav-link">Home</a></li>
    <li class="nav-item <?php echo $page == 'services' ? 'active' : ''; ?>"><a href="?p=services" class="nav-link">Services</a></li>
</ul>
```

el código funciona bien, pero a la hora de navegar entre las paginas la URL se muestra de la siguiente manera:

```
127.0.0.1/sitio/?p=services
```

y deseo que se muestre asi:

```
127.0.0.1/sitio/services
```

he intentado agregar algo como esto en mi htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+) /?p=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

pero no me ha funcionado.

Comment: ¿Has validado el valor de `$_GET['p']`? Por otro lado, incluir un archivo usando variables que son manipulables por el visitantes es **muy peligroso**. Si fe fijas `$page` es igual `$_GET['p']`, quere decir que si alguien quisiera intentar hackear tu sistema podría acceder a cualquier archivo simplemente cambiando la variable `p`

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario, ¿tienes alguna otra forma de poder cambiar la forma en la que navego en las paginas. he intentado buscar información y esa forma me pareció muy sencilla y la verdad quisiera cambiarla, por lo mismo de la seguridad.

Comment: Hola. Usa una regla de reescritura en .htaccess que dirija todas las solicitudes a un único archivo p.ej: index.php. Ubica todo tu código fuera del directorio público (en este sólo dejas imágenes, hojas de estilo, y scripts) que van a ser servidos con las páginas. En index invocas una clase que resuelva las direcciones y cargue y ejecute el código necesario para cada caso.

Comment: @Douglas la forma es sencilla, de eso no hay dudas. Se le puede agregar "seguridad" de muchas formas, por ejemplo, validando que `p` este en el "listado/arreglo" de "secciones/páginas" validas.